# MomentJS type definition with Typescript 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2015, momentjs, typescript2.0

Alright, my first question on SO, how exciting! :)

I am trying to get MomentJS definitions to work with Typescript 2.0.

I have no issues in getting Angular definitions to work, simply by doing `npm install @types/angular --save-dev`.

However, MomentJS (2.15.1) already comes with `moment.d.ts` as part of the package you get when you install it.

If you try to do a similar approach to angular, i.e. `npm install @types/moment --save-dev`, this is what you get:

> npm WARN deprecated @types/moment@2.13.0: This is a stub types definition for Moment (https://github.com/moment/moment). Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!

And surely enough, if you go to `node_modules\@types\moment`, there's nothing useful in there.

Yes, I have added the `tsconfig.json` file on my root folder, so Typescript 2.0 will automatically pick up the @types on node_modules (this is why Angular works fine), but for MomentJS I get the error below (since the .d.ts is not on the place where TS2 expects it to be):

> TS2304 Cannot find name 'moment'.

I also tried playing around with the `"typeRoots"` config on `tsconfig.json` without any luck.

This is the relevant piece of my `package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.16"
  },
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.15.1"
    }
}
```

I am using VS2015, if this matters.

So... Any ideas on how to get Typescript 2.0 to read the type definition for Moment, that sits on an "unexpected" folder?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I too have this problem

Comment: Having the same problem, for the moment I can't find a fix

Comment: I'm having this problem too, fwiw.

Comment: Ditto. Any solution? been wasting half a day.. please post if you have the answer.

Comment: To everyone asking whether I found a solution, no, I haven't. I eventually gave up. It was 8 months ago already. I can't even test whether the answers below would work, so maybe you guys can give it a try and let me know if they work, so I can mark as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You will find the `moment.d.ts` file under `node_modules\moment` since it is packaged with the moment itself.

With VS 2017 and TypeScript 2.2, you do not have to specify `typeRoots`; however, your environment may require specifying two or more of them such as:

`typeRoots: [ 'node_modules/@types/', 'node_modules/moment/' ]`

^ I forget if each `@types` subdirectory required an entry in `typeRoots`.

This is the process I use in *VS 2017* and *TypeScript 2.2* without any special changes to `tsconfig.json` (but this stuff changed in more recent versions):

It is automatically found via ES6 style import:

`import * as moment from "moment";`

This will import the functions named `moment` as well as the namespace `moment` merged into a single alias.

If you also want the `Moment` (return type) imported, perform the following as well:

`import { Moment } from "moment";`

In the current `moment.d.ts` (*2.18.1*), this type is otherwise inaccessible.

In the past I used `var moment = require("moment");` but that may not be possible in your setup unless you're running `browserify` or `requirejs` to convert the `CommonJS`/`AMD`-style require to something the browser supports.

Answer (score 3):

I found somewhere else (but don't remember where), that you should

change moment.d.ts by replacing export statement with

```
declare module 'moment' {
   export default moment;
}
```

add dummy file fixmoment.ts to your project with following line

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Compiling with tsc directly now compiles all files. Unfortunately VS2015 still gives an error 
*tsc : error TS2688: Build:Cannot find type definition file for 'moment'.*
which I don't understand.

Comment: Here's the reference:  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11864  The OP of the thread _seems_ to have been able to resolve by NOT adding the hack.  None of the steps mentioned in the thread work for me, however.   Workaround is still to do as @rekna states.

Comment: the import * as moment... didn't work for me but a reference like this worked:  /// <reference path="../wwwroot/lib/moment/moment.d.ts" />

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I read this [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10638#issuecomment-247478793) and add `declare var moment;` to `custom-typings.d.ts`. then it worked fine, but i don't understand why.

VS2015 SP3 + TypeScript2.0.6.0, angular2-webpack-starter based project.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following in a `customer-typings.d.ts` file worked for me

```
///<reference path="node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts"/>
import moment = Moment;
declare const moment: Moment;
```

I didn't even need to make any changes to ts `tsconfig.json` file